# Please help change keys nested inside dictionary

Tags: javascript, dictionary, parsing, nested, key

Hello I am beginner in javascript it would be great if you could help me

```
topicMessage = { topic: 'some_topic', messages: [{ 'myKey': '{"data": {"my name is ":"aman", "age": 22, "my ed": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}' }, { 'myKey2': '{ "data": { "my name is 2": "aman", "age": 22, "my ed 2": "btech" }, "meta": { "myAge2": 24, "school": "aps" } } ' }, { "myKey3": '{"data": {"my name is 3":"aman", "age": 22, "my ed 3": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}' } ] }
```

here inside messaages of topicMessages in data part we have to make keys dash separated, and value for mykey, mykey2, mykey3 are in string form, so need to convert JSON.parse to object first and then again convert it back to string, can somebody please help,
eg for messages in for value of myKey, which is a string inside that for key, data, value which is again an object, here key "my name is" becomes "my-name-is", "my ed" becomes "my-ed"

I am trying to do using this,

```
for(let i = 0; i < topicMessages.messages.length; i++){
    for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(topicMessages.messages[i])){
        for(const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(topicMessages.messages[i])){
            if(key1.includes(" ")){
                const newKey = key1.replace(/\s+/g, "-")
                topicMessages.messages[i][key]["data"][newkey] = topicMessages.messages[i][key]["data"][key1];
                delete topicMessages.messages[i][key]["data"][key1];         
}
}
}
}
```

expected output:

```
topicMessage = { topic: 'some_topic', messages: [{ 'myKey': '{"data": {"my-name-is ":"aman", "age": 22, "my-ed": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}' }, { 'myKey2': '{ "data": { "my-name-is-2": "aman", "age": 22, "my-ed-2": "btech" }, "meta": { "myAge2": 24, "school": "aps" } } ' }, { "myKey3": '{"data": {"my-name-is-3":"aman", "age": 22, "my-ed-3": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}' } ] }
```

```js
topicMessages = {
  topic: 'some_topic',
  messages: [{
    'myKey': '{"data": {"my name is ":"aman", "age": 22, "my ed": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}'
  }, {
    'myKey2': '{ "data": { "my name is 2": "aman", "age": 22, "my ed 2": "btech" }, "meta": { "myAge2": 24, "school": "aps" } } '
  }, {
    "myKey3": '{"data": {"my name is 3":"aman", "age": 22, "my ed 3": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}'
  }]
}

for (let i = 0; i < topicMessages.messages.length; i++) {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(topicMessages.messages[i])) {
    for (const [key1, value1] of Object.entries(topicMessages.messages[i])) {
      if (key1.includes(" ")) {
        const newKey = key1.replace(/\s+/g, "-")
        topicMessages.messages[i][key]["data"][newkey] = topicMessages.messages[i][key]["data"][key1];
        delete topicMessages.messages[i][key]["data"][key1];
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(topicMessages)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came out pretty ugly but it works

take a look

```js
const topicMessage = {
  topic: 'some_topic',
  messages: [{
    'myKey': '{"data": {"my name is ":"aman", "age": 22, "my ed": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}'
  }, {
    'myKey2': '{ "data": { "my name is 2": "aman", "age": 22, "my ed 2": "btech" }, "meta": { "myAge2": 24, "school": "aps" } } '
  }, {
    "myKey3": '{"data": {"my name is 3":"aman", "age": 22, "my ed 3": "btech"}, "meta": {"myAge":24, "school":"aps"}}'
  }]
}


const renameKeys = (data) =>
  data.map(o =>
    Object.keys(o).reduce((res, k) => {
      const json = o[k]
      const {data, ...rest} = JSON.parse(json)

      return {
        ...res,
        [k]: JSON.stringify({
          ...rest,
          data: Object.keys(data).reduce((res, key) => {
            return {
              ...res,
              [key.replace(/\s+/g, "-")]: data[key]
            }
          }, {})
        })
      }
    }, {})
  )





topicMessage.messages = renameKeys(topicMessage.messages)

console.log(topicMessage)
```

Comment: Thank you @R4ncid thank for your quick reply and working solution I am going through it also, let me check if, node js verison is below or above 12, would comment soon after. But again greatful

Comment: Hello @R4ncid, my node version is 9,  Object.fromEntries() is not supported, can you please tell any alternative for it.

Comment: * not my node version,node version of project I am working on is 9

Comment: @AmanKandari I changed my answer see if it works with your version of node

Comment: yes it is working, thank your answer, Sorry for late reply

Comment: Just one more query @R4ncid, why isn't output showing, meta part of string for all keys, myKey, myKey2, myKey3, only the data part

Comment: @AmanKandari you're right I edited my answer

Comment: just one last question, can you tell if key changes like from data to _data or something else inside myKey, how do i change code for that particular variable eg { myKey: '{"_data":{"my-name-is":"aman","age":22,"my-ed":"btech"}}' }